# How to add shake animation to a view (react-native)?

Tags: react-native

I want to shake the below `View` when my password is wrong.
for example:

it should be translateX from place 10, to place 20 for 4 time and 1 second.
then should be stopped in place 10.

place 10 (I mean the X position of `View`)

```
startShake = () => {
   Animated.loop(
       Animated.sequence([
         Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: 1, duration: 150, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
         Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: -1, duration: 300, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
         Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: 0, duration: 150, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
       ])
   ).start();
}

<Animated.View style={{transform: [{
    translateX: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0],
        outputRange: [0, 0]
     })
  }]
}}>

</Animated.View>
```

Comment: it's a loop, can I just get a shaking when I have an error ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thank you for all answers.

I just solved editing my code with the following code

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.shakeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

 startShake = () => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 10, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
      Animated.timing(this.shakeAnimation, { toValue: -10, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
      Animated.timing(this.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 10, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
      Animated.timing(this.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 0, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true })
    ]).start();
 }

 <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{translateX: this.shakeAnimation}] }}>  

 </Animated.View>
```

Comment: Hi, do i not call startShake function at all?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the shake animation for Image component in react native, you can check it-

```
const bgImage = require('./components/images/ex.jpg')

class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
   }

   handleAnimation = () => {
   // A loop is needed for continuous animation
   Animated.loop(
     // Animation consists of a sequence of steps
     Animated.sequence([
       // start rotation in one direction (only half the time is needed)
       Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: 1.0, duration: 150, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
       // rotate in other direction, to minimum value (= twice the duration of above)
       Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: -1.0, duration: 300, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
       // return to begin position
       Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: 0.0, duration: 150, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true})
     ])
   ).start(); 
   }
 }
```

To add this Animation to Image Component-

```
<Animated.Image
  source={bgImage}
  resizeMode='contain'
  style={{
    transform: [{
    rotate: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
       inputRange: [-1, 1],
       outputRange: ['-0.1rad', '0.1rad']
      })
    }]
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a library : [react-native-animitable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)

You can do wonders using this library and is really very easy to use with least codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without loop.

```
startShake = () => {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue,
        {
            toValue: 1, 
            duration: 150,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }
    ).start()
}

<Animated.View style={{transform: [{
    translateX: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1],
        outputRange: [10, 20, 10, 20, 10]
     })
  }]
}}>

</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might some help you to get your required animation

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  handleAnimation = () => {
    // A loop is needed for continuous animation
    Animated.loop(
      // Animation consists of a sequence of steps
      Animated.sequence([
        // start rotation in one direction (only half the time is needed)
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: 1.0, duration: 150, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
        // rotate in other direction, to minimum value (= twice the duration of above)
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: -1.0, duration: 300, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true}),
        // return to begin position
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {toValue: 0.0, duration: 150, easing: Easing.linear, useNativeDriver: true})
      ])
    ).start(); 
  }
}

<Animated.View
  style={{
    transform: [{
      rotate: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [-1, 1],
        outputRange: ['-0.1rad', '0.1rad']
      })
    }]
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// @flow
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Image, Animated } from 'react-native'

// Constants
const DEFAULT_STEP_TIME = 1000

interface Props {
  source: string | number;
  intensity?: number;
  stepTime?: number;
  iterations?: number;
  containerStyle?: any;
  style?: any;
}

const ShakingIcon = ({
  source,
  intensity = 2,
  stepTime,
  iterations = 2,
  containerStyle,
  style,
}: Props) => {
  const interval = useRef(null)
  const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0))

  const shakeAnimation = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(animation.current, {
          toValue: -intensity,
          duration: 50,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(animation.current, {
          toValue: intensity,
          duration: 50,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(animation.current, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 50,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]),
      { iterations },
    ).start()
  }, [])

  const runAnimation = useCallback(async () => {
    interval.current = setInterval(
      () => shakeAnimation(),
      stepTime || DEFAULT_STEP_TIME,
    )
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation()
    return () => clearInterval(interval.current)
  }, [])

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        containerStyle,
        { transform: [{ translateX: animation.current }] },
      ]}
    >
      <Image source={source} style={style} />
    </Animated.View>
  )
}

export default ShakingIcon
```

based on https://snack.expo.dev/embedded/@ananthu.kanive/shake?iframeId=t099o2svbu&preview=true&platform=web&theme=light

Answer (score 0):

It can be a good solution with two axes:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Easing } from "react-native";

const Shake = () => {
    const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

    const startAnimation = () => {
        animation.setValue(0);
        Animated.timing(animation, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 1500,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(()=>{
            animation.setValue(0)
        });
    }

    const animatedStyles = {
        transform: [
            {
                translateX: animation.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
                    outputRange: [0, 10, -10, 10, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                })
            },
            {
                translateY: animation.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
                    outputRange: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, -10, 10, -10, 0]
                })
            }
        ]
    }

    return <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={startAnimation}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyles]} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 600,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
    box: {
        backgroundColor: "tomato",
        width:150,
        height:150
    }
});

export default Shake
```